# how can I use @ rules in emotion?

Tags: css, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I wanna use @Property in emotion ,but cannot find something about this in document

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import React from 'react';
import demo from './demo_img.jpeg';
const ComponentMaskImage = () => {
  return <MaskImage src={demo} />;
};
export default ComponentMaskImage;


  @property -m-0 {
    syntax: '<number>';
    initial-value: 1;
    inherits: false;
  }
const MaskImage = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(${(props) => props.src});
  mask: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--m-0)),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--m-0))
  );
  transition: --m-0 0.5s;
  &:hover {
    --m-0: 0;
  }
`;
```

Does emotion support @rules?

can use @rules in styled-component

Answer (score 0):

note it

```
const m1Property = `
  @property --m-1 {
  syntax: '<number>';
  initial-value: 1;
  inherits: false;
}`;
const MaskImage = styled.div`
    ${m0Property}
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).